# Flex As3 - Static Variable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, static

How can i preserve a variables value , so that i can re-use that when i run my application again ? What i've tried to do is:

```
package content.util
```

{
    public class StaticTest
    {
        public static var testStatic:int;
    }
}

and in my application i'm doing something like this:

```
StaticTest.testStatic = 5;
```

but when i'm reloading the app my static variable always set to 0. Shouldn't it be preserving the value "5" ?? please Help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you do not save it. If you close your application all data is gone.

Try putting it to a SharedObject.